# create an input select box that is dependent on a previous input choice in shiny and r

Tags: r, shiny

i want to take two select input boxes in which ...

first one will print the label like 'raj' and 'other'
the second one will print the 30 names of the district when raj is clicked and 34 names of state when other is clicked.
both raj and other and nothing but labels and this list of district and states will be fetched from ms SQL server as a stored procedure so i gotta use them as dtd$DistrictName and dtd2$StateName both are in the database, different queries that's why i stored them in different variables like dtd and dtd2.
anyone knows how to print the dtd$DistrictName when label from select box 1 raj is clicked in other selectbox and same for another label named other

i don't know how to approach this problem, i have tried couple of code from the web and this is one of them but didn't work for me

```
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)
library(shiny)
library(psych) 

dbcnd <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=;Database=;Uid=;Pwd=''")
qrydd<<-paste("exec db..[sp_name] '0','0','','0','','01/01/2017','31/12/2017'")
    qrydd
    dtd <<- sqlQuery(dbcnd,qrydd)
    dtd <<- data.frame(dtd)
    dtd

qrydd2<<-paste("exec db..[sp_name]'','','','','0','0','2','0','','01/01/2017','31/12/2017'")
    qrydd2
    dtd2 <<- sqlQuery(dbcnd,qrydd2)
    dtd2 <<- data.frame(dtd2)
    dtd2

countyData = data.frame("raj"=dtd$DistrictName,"other_state"=dtd2$StateName,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 ui = shinyUI(
 fluidPage( 
 titlePanel("Reactive select input boxes"),

 sidebarPanel( 
 htmlOutput("state"),
 htmlOutput("district")
 ),

mainPanel(
 plotOutput("plot1") 
           )
       ) )



 server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {


output$state = renderUI({ 
 selectInput(inputId = "raj", 
 label = "raj:", 
 choices = as.character(unique(countyData$raj))) 
 })
 output$district = renderUI({

data_available = countyData[countyData$raj == input$raj, "other_state"]


selectInput(inputId = "other_state", 
 label = "other_state:", 
 choices = unique(data_available), 
 selected = unique(data_available)[1])
 })

# output$plot1 = renderPlot({
#  map('county', region = input$state)
# 
#  map('county', region =paste(input$state,input$county, sep=','),
#  add = T, fill = T, col = 'red')
#  
#  })
 })


 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

See below! I see you are new to posting, in the future please provide a reproducible example... we can't run your queries and therefore have to guess how the dataset is set up.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


rm(list=ls())

 ui = shinyUI(
 fluidPage( 
  titlePanel("Reactive select input boxes"),

   sidebarPanel( 
     uiOutput("FirstChoice"),
     uiOutput("SecondChoice")
   ),

    mainPanel()
  )
 )

 server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   countyData = data.frame("Raj"=c("District 1","District 2", "District 3"),"State"=c("State 1","State 2","State 3"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   output$FirstChoice <- renderUI ({ 
      selectInput(inputId = "FirstChoice",label = "Raj/State",
                  choices = c("Raj","State"))
   })

   output$SecondChoice <- renderUI ({

     sub <- select(countyData, input$FirstChoice)

     if (input$FirstChoice == "Raj"){lab <- "Raj"}
     else if (input$FirstChoice == "State") {lab <- "State"}
     else {lab <- "dependant"}

     selectInput(inputId = "SecondChoice", label = lab,
                 choices = c(get(input$FirstChoice,sub)))
   }) 

 })


 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

***Update based on OP's comments***

> let's say if we consider the your given solution, what if i wanna do
>   it like below-given scenario:
>   countyData = data.frame("Raj"=c("District 1","District 2", "District 3","District
>   4"),"State"=c("State 1","State 2","State 3"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
>   where districts are of length 4 and state are of size 3

If you have different lengths, you can't create a `data.frame` but you can create a `list` which acts very similar.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)


rm(list=ls())

ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage( 
    titlePanel("Reactive select input boxes"),

    sidebarPanel( 
      uiOutput("FirstChoice"),
      uiOutput("SecondChoice")
    ),

    mainPanel()
  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  countyData = list("Raj"=c("District 1","District 2", "District 3","District 4"),"State"=c("State 1","State 2","State 3"))


  output$FirstChoice <- renderUI ({ 
    selectInput(inputId = "FirstChoice",label = "Raj/State",
                choices = c("Raj","State"))
  })

  output$SecondChoice <- renderUI ({

    if (input$FirstChoice == "Raj"){lab <- "Raj"}
    else if (input$FirstChoice == "State") {lab <- "State"}
    else {lab <- "dependant"}

    selectInput(inputId = "SecondChoice", label = lab,
                choices = c(get(input$FirstChoice,countyData)))
  }) 

})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As for your comment...

> inputvalue<- data.frame(a=c("Ajmer","Alwar","Banswara","Baran","Barmer"), b=c("Chittorgarh","Churu","Dausa","Dholpur","Dungarpur"))
>   countyData =data.frame("Raj"= c(inputvalue$a),"State"=c(inputvalue$b), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) and
>   why this prints number instead of real vector values like
>   "Ajmer","Alwar","Banswara" and so on

The issue is your `inputvalue` is not using `stringsAsFactors` which causes everything to be class Factor which is why you are seeing numbers. Also, the above is redundant code when you can just do..

```
countyData = data.frame("Raj" = c("Ajmer","Alwar","Banswara","Baran","Barmer"), "State" = c("Chittorgarh","Churu","Dausa","Dholpur","Dungarpur"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks for your help and suggestion, i will take care next time

Comment: countyData = data.frame("Raj"=c(dtd$DistrictName),"State"=c(dtd1$StateName),stringsAsFactors = FALSE),throwing an error different number of rows bcoz query1 contains 34 records and query2 contains 33 records,do you know how to get it right

Comment: and even though i use the same stored procedure(just for testing) to avoid this, why is this giving numbers like(1,2,3 till 34) in sub-menu instead of names of the 34 district. could you please guide me through what I am doing wrong here

Comment: let's say if we consider the your given solution, what if i wanna do it like below-given scenario: ----------------countyData = data.frame("Raj"=c("District 1","District 2", "District 3","District 4"),"State"=c("State 1","State 2","State 3"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE) where districts are of length 4 and state are of size 3

Comment: and snippet for a second relevant problem is: ----------------inputvalue<-data.frame(a=c("Ajmer","Alwar","Banswara","Baran","Barmer"),b=c("Chittorgarh","Churu","Dausa","Dholpur","Dungarpur")) 
   countyData =data.frame("Raj"= c(inputvalue$a),"State"=c(inputvalue$b),stringsAsFactors = FALSE) and why this prints number instead of real vector values like "Ajmer","Alwar","Banswara" and so on

Comment: thanks,it's working quite well for me, thanks again for your help and bearing with me on this issue but i have got one problem to address though, why is it showing numbers(literally numbers)like 1,2,3 as there are 34 records in the first list(raj) so it is displaying  34 numbers and 33 for the second one(other), could you please tell me why it is so

Comment: what i have tried... countyData = list("Raj"=as.list(paste(as.character(dtd$DistrictName))),"State"=as.list(paste(as.character(dtd$DistrictName)))),but when i click on any of these dropdown list value from selectbox it will render a chart as per specific id assigned to it,let's take scenario when district one is clicked it would plot a chart according to it 101 from the database and so on, but when i checked the inspect element for that output what it is  passing to database, it was just string values like district1 while i wanna show it as district1 but pass to DB as 101 to plot the chart

Comment: hi @siddharthsharma , I don't understand how the dropdowns are displaying numbers... it doesn't show in my example so if it's a problem, it has to be with your dataset and since you didn't provide one to go off of, it's hard to help. Your second question about passing not the name to the DB for the graph but the number is a different question and not in your original ask (nor should it be now).

Answer (score 0):

```
Values = c(dtd$DID)
   names(Values) = as.list(as.character(dtd$DistrictName))
   
   values1=c(dtd1$StateCode)
   names(values1)=as.list(as.character(dtd1$StateName))
  
  countyData = list("Raj"=Values,"State"=values1)
```

[image]

dummy dataset:
**stored procedure1**

```
DID DistrictName    BlockName   CenterName  TotRaj  TotOtherState   StateCode
101   a                null        null     564534  564534            null
201   b                null        null     675645  765645            null
301   c                null        null     765645  786756            null
401   d                null        null     987656  764534            null
501   e                null        null     675645  543423            null
601   f                null        null     765434  231234            null
701   g                null        null     564534  763423            null
801   h                null        null     234565  567876            null
901   i                null        null     985646  876345            null
102   j                null        null     876754  453675            null
202   k                null        null     876756  876754            null
```

**stored procedure 2:**

```
DID DistrictName    BlockName   StateCode TotRaj    TotOtherState   StateName   
101      a            aaa         1111  564534  564534  sdd          null
101      a            bbb         2222  675645  765645  bdd          null
101      a            ccc         3333  765645  786756  cdd          null
101      a            ddd         4444  987656  764534  eff          null
101      a            eee         5555  675645  543423  ghh          null
101      a            fff         6666  765434  231234  sdg          null
101      a            ggg         7777  564534  763423  ghj          null
101      a            hhh         8888  234565  567876  lkj          null
101      a            iii         9999  985646  876345  fgh          null
101      a            jjj         1011  876754  453675  dfs          null
101      a            kkk         2011  876756  876754  fgd          null
101      a            aaa         3011  5678    5645    sdf          null
101      a            aaa         4011  6756    4534    mnb          null
```

output screenshot:
[image]

inspect element key values:
[image]